# d3.json() not working when using URL from the browser containing my JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

I have a JSON data that is found on my URL:
[image: JSON]

and i'm trying to use it using d3.json() for my charts but it won't return anything.
below is my code:

```
var defaultHighAvailStaticUrl = "/highAvailabilities/" + defaultDate;
console.log(defaultHighAvailStaticUrl);

d3.json(defaultHighAvailStaticUrl, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);

})
```

I don't know what is wrong. Also is it more easier if I use ajax instead? Since it's a lot more clearer to use i think but i don't know how to call the data in the d3.js chart functions especially on the `.data()` of d3. Do i need to use the $.each or should i just shoot on the d3.js codes?

Ajax code i'm planning to use:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $.ajax({
        url: (defaultHighAvailStaticUrl ),
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: (data) => {
            $.each(data, (key, val) => {

            });
        }
    })
});
```

console result:
[image: console_result]

Comment: can you put the screenshot for browser console from output page ?

Comment: @altocumulus version 5.15.0